# extract rar files to folder

Tags: linux, opensuse, rar

I tried googling around and checked the man page but couldn't find what I was looking for.

Basically need to extract a rar archive to a separate volume. I know:

```
rar e archive.rar
```

will extract it to the current folder but I want to extract it to somewhere else. Can this be achieved without having to first move the archive to that location?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
rar x archive.rar path/to/extract/to
```

Worked.

Comment: What if I want to unrar many files, each file is unrar'ed to a folder with the same name? So If I've file1.rar, file2.rar,..etc, I want with a single command to unrar file1.rar to folder named file1, file2.rar to file2, and so on.

Comment: unrar x c:/archive.rar dir .. says no files to extract, unrar 4.20 on win7, solution use backslashes and slash after output dir: unrar x c:\archive.rar dir/

Comment: Note that the path need to end with a backslash or else it would interpret it as 'extract specified file from archive' instead of 'extract archive to directory' unless the directory already exist.

Answer (score 2):

unrar x /define/path/to/extract/